# Add support for in-line spoilers

Tags: feature-request, markdown, spoilers

I would like to request an option for in-line spoilers on Stack Exchange.

For example, instead of needing to spoiler tag an entire sentence:

> Hiding spoilers is good manners.

Or breaking up a sentence with a dedicated spoiler line:

Hiding

> spoilers

is good manners.

I'd like to spoiler tag a single word from a sentence. I propose borrowing Discord's spoiler syntax of double pipes:

[image: Hiding spoilers is good manners]

```
Hiding ||spoilers|| is good manners.
```

Comment: "I'm writing this C programming expression and I can't get A || B || C to work" -> "I'm writing this C programming expression and I can't get A HIDDENSPOILER C to work" -> click on spoiler -> "I can't get A B C to work". This would break a lot of existing posts for a feature with very limited use.

Comment: @Lundin 1) It doesn't have to be this exact syntax. 2) More importantly, code should always be formatted as code anyway; either inline or in a block. Many things already break if you write "code" as text. For example: "I can't get the <img> tag to work" --> "I can't get the tag to work". I'd say this is a nice feature to have, especially on non-programming sites.

Comment: @41686d6564 Regardless, there's just some 4-5 sites where it would actually be useful: the puzzle sites and the sites dealing with fiction.